# Failing to read values from a file

Tags: c++, fstream

The program below should read in a bunch of integers from a file and work out their average:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    ifstream fin( "mydata.txt" );
    int i, value, sum = 0;

    for ( i = 0; fin >> value; i++ )
    {
        sum += value;
    }

    if ( i > 0 )
    {
        ofstream fout( "average.txt" );
        fout << "Average: " << ( sum / i ) << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cerr << "No list to average!" << endl;
    }

system( "PAUSE" );

}
```

The file `mydata.txt` exists in the same directory and contains `1 2 3 4 5` but the output is always: `No list to average!`

What am I doing wrong that it always skips the calculation and output file generation parts?

Thanks for your help,

H

Comment: What do you mean same directory ? As in your source files ? or in the same as the built executable ?? It works fine for me in Linux.

Comment: Call `fin.is_open()` to see if the file has been opened properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i guess mydata.txt is not in the same directory as the executable, the code works for me

Answer (score 3):

After you open the file, add an `assert` statement to make sure you've got the path correct.

```
ifstream fin( "mydata.txt" );
assert(fin.good());
```

If the assertion fails, you'll know something is probably wrong with your file path.

Comment: I would prefer to see this as an error check in the code.  File open can always fail, and good code would handle that.

Comment: Yes, that's a good point.  Proper C++ code should always check the state of a file stream after opening a file, since no exception will be thrown if an error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `mydata.txt` with the absolute path